# Sublime text 2/3: How to move cursor along indentation? Mac OS

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm trying to move the cursor along the indentation level. A "jump to the next or previous same-indentation-line"-command.

To illustrate:
The "|" is supposed to be the cursor.

```
def way_too_big_method
  |block1
    block2
      Way too many things happening...
    end
  end
end
```

***Command: Move down along indentation***

```
def way_too_big_method
  block1
    block2
      Way too many things happening...
    end
  |end
end
```

I know you can do that in vim (maybe you need a plugin) and I know I could use cold folding for that, but it would be three commands (fold, move down, unfold). I used Textmate some years ago and I thought it was just ALT+UP/DOWN but I might be wrong.

Do you know a way to do that? I would go for a plugin if it's sublime 3 compatible (It would be quite easy to create as well, I guess), but I have the feeling that this must be implemented in sublime-core somewhere, right?

Thanks for any idea on this one!
Andy

Comment: Using both ST2 and ST3 on Windows I can move down the indentation line with no problems. Are you trying to jump directly down to the end of `block2` with only one keypress?

Comment: No just to the "end" of block1. I'm developing on a mac. Maybe this is OS specific. I'll check my keyboard settings. What keystroke are you using to jump down?

Comment: I think that @TheMahrvin 's talking about a "jump to the next same-indentation-line" command. From _block1_ to _end_ in one single step.

Comment: @Igncaio: Yes. That is what I'm talking about. I'll add your wording to my question, if you don't mind. BTW: I couldn't find any mac specific keyboard settings for ALT/OPTION-DOWN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been missing this functionality from TextMate too, so I wrote a plugin that does it. You can find it [here](https://github.com/mwean/sublime_jump_along_indent). I wrote it specifically on ST3, but it should probably also work on ST2. Make an issue in Github if you have any issues with it.